# Confused about bounties

Tags: support, bounties

How can [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3992346/how-to-work-with-videos-in-asp-net) have a bounty of +100 if the [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/341806/sam) offering it has only 6 point in reputation?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does the bounty system work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you offer a bounty you immediately lose the reputation. So the user had 106 reputation. Then he offered 100 of his points as a bounty and now he has 6.